# Coldfusion not sending email

Tags: email, coldfusion

I am having problems with this website, it isn't sending any emails. Basically when someone places a order, it sends a comfirmation email. I don't see any problems with the code but I believe this is the right place to be looking for the problem. Can some one help me please?

```
<cfquery name="getUser" datasource="personal2009">
SELECT * FROM site_users WHERE id = '#session.id#'
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>
    <cfmail to="#site_email#" from="#site_email#" subject="Website International Order Request">
    #getUser.title# #getUser.Firstname# #getUser.Surname# has requested to deliver an order to an international address.

    Their contact details are:
    #getUser.Address1#
    #getUser.Address2#
    #getUser.Town#
    #getUser.Postcode#
    #getUser.Country#

    #getUser.Tel#
    #getUser.email#

    The delivery address requested is:
    #formtitle# #formFirstname# #formSurname#
    #formAddress1#
    #formAddress2#
    #formTown#
    #formPostcode#

    The order details are:
    <cfset thisrow = 0><cfoutput><cfset thisrow = thisrow + 1><cfset tot = 0><cfloop index="list" from="1" to="#session.numincart#"><CFQUERY NAME="ind" DATASOURCE="personal2009" maxrows=1>SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = #listgetat(session.cart, list)#</CFQUERY>
    Product Name: #ind.product_name#
    Price: £#decimalformat(listgetat(session.price, list))#<cfset multiply2 = #listgetat(session.quant, list)#>
    Quantity: #listgetat(session.quant, list)#

    </cfloop></cfoutput>
    Thank you

    </cfmail>
</cfoutput>
<cfset session.endemail = '1'>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a code issue and not a problem with the email server?  If you are NOT on a shared hosting, confirm your email settings by going into the CF Admin and clicking on the "Mail" link under "Server Settings".  Don't change any settings, click on the "Verify mail server connection" and press "Submit Changes".  If all is well, you should get a green "Connection Verification Successful."

Comment: Did you check the mailsent log?  By the way, cfmail has a built in cfoutput feature so you don't need the tags surrounding it.

Comment: First thing you should do is check the mail logs. That should tell you pretty quickly if there's a code/configuration problem, or if you're actually sending a mail and it's getting blocked somewhere downstream.

Comment: From LiveDocs: 
http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=email_02.html

Error logging and undelivered messages
ColdFusion logs all errors that occur during SMTP message processing to the file mail.log in the ColdFusion log directory. The log entries contain the date and time of the error as well as diagnostic information about why the error occurred.

Comment: If a message is not delivered because of an error, ColdFusion writes it to this directory:

In Windows: \CFusion\Mail\Undelivr
On UNIX: /opt/coldfusion/mail/undelivr
The error log entry that corresponds to the undelivered message contains the name of the file written to the UnDelivr (or undelivr) directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what your hosting environment looks like, I may suggest altering your cfmail tag to the following:

```
<cfmail to="#site_email#" from="#site_email#" subject="Website International Order Request" server="#server#" username="#username#" password="#password#">
```

1) If you don't have access to the CFADMIN, you are unable to track your mail path.  Specifying your own server/username/password will allow you to send email with your own SMTP server and rule that out.

2) Even if your host has CFMAIL setup with a SMTP default server, it may be possible that they have not setup SMTP relaying correctly.  The outcome is your mail gets sent through coldfusion but rejected by the smtp server.

3) Even if your host has CFMAIL setup and SMTP relaying setup, the last possibility could be SPAM filters on the receiving end.  If you have SPAM filters that look at SPF/Domain Keys/other criteria, they could be blocking to emails too.

Specifying your own server/username/password is usually the best bet to troubleshooting email issues.

Comment: Thanks! This has helped me, I have worked on your suggestions now but I have no access to the email to test it, so I am waiting for my friend to tell me weather she is receiving the emails now or not.